# Product page Script Not Pulling SKU, Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, products, prototype-js

Having trouble inserting a pretty simple tracking code into each product page.
  I am not having any luck pulling the SKU from the product page to populate the `product_id` (see below).  
I am attempting to do so via a widget - which may be causing an issue, though I have inserted code this way before.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var sidecar = sidecar || {};
        sidecar.product_info = {
        product_id: '1234'
        };
    </script>
```

Any idea on what code to use so `'1234'` will dynamically populate with our SKU?  Also, product id would be an acceptable substitute if, for whatever reason, it's easier to do so.

Comment: You want to get product SKU on product detail page or Magento or somewhere else ?

Comment: The Product detail page is preferred - thanks!

Comment: I think the code below will work, now I just can't figure out where to insert it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use below code to get product Id in Product detail page:

```
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
        var sidecar = sidecar || {};
        sidecar.product_info = {
        product_id: '<?php echo $_product->getId();?>'
        };
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks man, still having issues - is there a location on the page it needs to be?

Comment: It can be place anywhere in the page. Currently on product detail page how the product name is showing? Please share that code. Also is that the default Magento's product detail page or its your custom page?

Comment: I'm thinking it might  be related to using a static block and widget to insert the code.

Comment: Had to add to the bottom of view.phtml in catalog/product